# How did I manage to combine O and c to © in PuTTY?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, freebsd, special-characters

Today's mystery: I was going to type the word "Och", meaning "and" in Swedish. However, I ended up with ©h, and I don't know why, and I cannot reproduce it. The chain of software is as follows.

- Windows 7 using Swedish keyboard layout.
- PuTTY connected to FreeBSD 9.1, using UTF8 encoding.
- Running a `screen` session.
- An `irssi` session running in the `screen`.

Even though I cannot reproduce it, I'm assuming I must have pressed something wrong, which somehow combined the characters O and c into a copyright sign. Since I cannot reproduce it, I also cannot narrow down which component in the chain produced the spurious © character. Please help me solve this mystery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You found the [Compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key).** When pressed, it takes the next few keypresses (usually two) and translates them to a similar special character.

While no longer a [physical key](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/plain/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre) on most keyboards, some environments (particularly X11 on Linux/BSDs) still support it and allow remapping another, unused key (often Caps Lock or something equally useless) for the Compose function.

On Windows there is no Compose support (aside from [third-party projects](https://code.google.com/p/freecompose/)); however, **PuTTY interprets the [<kbd>≣ Menu</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) key as Compose,** and there is an option to do the same with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

So it's possible that you accidentally pressed <kbd>≣ Menu</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> resulting in ©.

*(Here's the full [compose table](https://git.tartarus.org/?p=simon/putty.git;a=blob;f=windows/winucs.c;h=14728a815a86c46d9f1881dfc6c76d4381d46248;hb=2713396c91fa6ba00c40940450ffcc3953aba4ee#l649) found in PuTTY source code; a bit smaller than [the X.org one](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/plain/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre).)*

---

Your next quest is to find the [any key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Keyboard-anykey.jpg).

Comment: Interesting. Is this actually documented anywhere? The only reference to a compose-like feature in PuTTY that I could find, was the option to enable alt gr as a DEC-like compose key.